# Which event is called when a user click on the disabled item in context menu?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have button, which displays a Context menu. In the menu are few items (some of them are disabled - setEnabled(false)).

Which event is called when a user click on the disabled item? It's not onContextItemSelected nor onContextMenuClosed. But the menu is closed after the click.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There probably isn't one. If it's disabled it's not clickable. Why would an event fire?

Comment: I tried it only in emulator. But the disabled item seems to be clickable, at least the menu disappear after click. So the onContextMenuClosed should be fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consultation with my teacher, I've solved the problem. You can check the focus of your window, and then decide if the context menu was closed or not.

So you have to:

1. Use the code below.
2. Call **onPrepareContextMenu()** method when you create the context menu.

The code:

```
public class MyActivity extends android.app.Activity {

    private boolean contextMenuDisplayed = false;

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if(hasFocus && this.contextMenuDisplayed) {
            this.contextMenuDisplayed = false;
            this.onContextMenuClosed(null);
        }
    }

    public void onPrepareContextMenu() {
        this.contextMenuDisplayed  = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated. This fixed my issue with opening up two context menus at once. Cheers