# Preventing a View from showing two Context Menus

Tags: android

In my Android application I have a Button which opens up a context menu when clicked. The issue is that if a user clicks quickly, they can open multiple instances of the menu.

```
b.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick( View view ) {
    // popup options            
    view.showContextMenu();
}
} );
```

How can I prevent the user from opening up more than one copy? I am looking for a 'boolean' like checking the Visible status, but can't seem to find anything. My hope was that there was a function somehow that would result in code similar to:

```
if (context menu is not open)
     open context menu
else 
     don't do anything
```

Comment: "In my Android application I have a Button which opens up a context menu when clicked." -- why?

Comment: Client requirements. As odd as it sounds, it seems to provide a pretty good user experience, (i.e. it pops up and gives the user a list of values they can use to start related activities.

Comment: But why not an `AlertDialog` or a `PopupMenu`?

Comment: Well, `AlertDialog` isn't what I'm looking for, and the `PopupMenu` isn't quite right either; and the developer that made the final decision to use a `ContextMenu` has left... Is there any way to do this? Basically the client already signed-off on the Context Menu look & feel, and I can't change it too much without raising some eyebrows :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't like this UI pattern. It's this sort of thing that cause iOS developers (and users) to think that Android developers lack discipline. Context menus are for long-presses, period. Use something else, like an `AlertDialog` or `PopupMenu`, elsewhere.

That being said, set a `boolean` flag when you show the context menu, checking it first to prevent duplicate menus. Clear the flag in `onContextMenuClosed()`.

Comment: Turns out this didn't work for me. onContextMenuClosed does not get called for some reason. The solution mentioned here worked, however:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045085/which-event-is-called-when-a-user-click-on-the-disabled-item-in-context-menu