# How can I highlight an item which was long-pressed to create a ContextMenu?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have a RecyclerView in which each item can be long-pressed to show a context menu. I'd like to highlight the item which was long-pressed, so that the user can see and visually confirm which item it was before they select anything in the menu (so they don't delete the wrong item by mistake, for instance).

I can get the item to highlight ok, by adding a background colour, but I can't get it to un-highlight if the user then closes the context menu (or if the selected menu item is one which doesn't take the user to a new activity).

I have the following to create the menu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    if (v.getId()==R.id.list_item) {
        // Highlight selected item
     v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.browser_actions_bg_grey));
        // Inflate menu
        MenuInflater inflater = this.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_long_press_chart_name, menu);
    }
}
```

I assume I need to do something in `onContextMenuClosed`, but I can't see what I need to do:

```
public void onContextMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
        super.onContextMenuClosed(menu);
}
```

I can't see anything in the `menu` variable that shows which item opened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by doing the following in onContextMenuClosed (mRecyclerView is the RecyclerView that holds all the items):

```
public void onContextMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    super.onContextMenuClosed(menu);

    View thisItem;

    for(int ii=0; ii< mRecyclerView.count(); ii++) {
       thisItem = mRecyclerView.getChildAt(ii);
       if(thisItem.getId() == R.id.list_item) {
           thisItem.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.fui_transparent));
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147412/2912553) which offers a way of getting notified when context menu is closed.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't really lead me to the answer.